# react-hook-form and Yup array

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, yup

I'm using React hook form and Yup. How to validate that the first child must have both a name and age (required), while the subsequent children do not need to have them

```
const parentSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  name: Yup.string().required('Name is required'),
  children: Yup.array().of(
    Yup.object().shape({
      'name.0': Yup.string().required('Name is required'),
      'age.0': Yup.number().required('Age is required'),
    })
  ),
});

const parent = {
  name: 'Lalala',
  children: [
    {
      name: 'Child #1',
      age: 24,
    },
    {
      name: 'Child #2',
    },
    {
      age: 48,
    }
  ],
};
```

Any help is appreciated!